# Merge [tag:trackpad] into [tag:touchpad]

Tags: discussion, tags

The former ([trackpad](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trackpad)) is currently a duplicate of the latter ([touchpad](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/touchpad)) when it should really be an alias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agreed, I have merged and linked them.